# Possible to have hx-get "echo" client-side to avoid a server-side echo of HX-Target?

Tags: htmx

I'm kicking the tires of HTMX and specifically the client-side-templates extension.

Let's say I have three buttons with an ancestor hx-get that has a mustache-template attribute. That template handles all three buttons, and has conditional logic for that purpose. I know that I could make a server-side endpoint that just echoes back the HX-Target, etc. so the template knows what was clicked on. I'm wondering if there's a way to do that strictly client-side without the need of such a server-side echo.

Comment: I was just researching this further and came upon this existing htmx proposal which is similar to what I'm after

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/960